# Can't show text with transition

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/Sprudeldude/pen/aNKmMb

```css
.verborgen{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.wrap
{
    color: black;
    width:200px;
    height: 20px;

    transition: height 1s, width 1s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */

}

.wrap:hover .verborgen
{
    visibility: visible;
    background: #999;
    height:200px;
    width: 500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
                <h2>Medewerkers</h2>
                          <div class="verborgen">
                            <div>Persoon 1</div>
                            <div>Persoon 2</div>
                            <div>Persoon 3</div>
                    </div>
```

When i hover over "Medewerkers", it shows a box with in the box: Persoon 1, Persoon 2 and Persoon 3.

This part of the code works, but the transition and hover-effect doesn't work anymore.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two problems:

1. You can't animate (transition) anything that changes from
   `visibility: hidden` to `visibility: visibile` or from `display:
   none` to something which is not `none`.
2. The transitioning element is `.verborgen`, and not `.wrap`, so the
   transition should be applied to it.

```css
.verborgen{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #999;
    -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: height 1s, width 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
    transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}

.wrap
{
    color: black;
    width:200px;
    height: 20px;

    transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}

.wrap:hover .verborgen
{
    height:200px;
    width: 500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
                <h2>Medewerkers</h2>
                          <div class="verborgen">
                            <div>Persoon 1</div>
                            <div>Persoon 2</div>
                            <div>Persoon 3</div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: And is there a way that when the animation start, my scrollbar moves with it ?

Comment: Not a CSS only solution as far as I know.